# On solving Planar Circuit SAT

Tags: ds.algorithms, circuit-complexity, sat, counting-complexity, circuit-depth

This enquiry is three-sided.

**Side 1 - State of the art**

> 1. Which is the best known algorithm for $\text{PLANAR-CIRCUIT-SAT}$?
> 2. Which is the best known algorithm for $\text{PLANAR-CIRCUIT-SAT}$ assuming sublinear depth?
> 3. Which is the best known algorithm for $\oplus \text{PLANAR-CIRCUIT-SAT}$?
> 4. Which is the best known algorithm for $\oplus \text{PLANAR-CIRCUIT-SAT}$ assuming sublinear depth?

**Side 2 - Clusters of variables**
I'm about to implement a $\oplus \text{PLANAR-CIRCUIT-SAT}$ solver, which running time is supposed to be exponential in $d_C + d_V$, where $d_C$ is the depth of the input circuit, and $d_V$ is a quantity which represents to what extent the variables of the circuit are grouped in clusters. Very informally, a high $d_V$ (linear in the number of input variables) means that the wires connecting the input variables to their gates are scattering back and forth all over the circuit, traversing it from left to right, thus such variables are not clustered and somehow exhibit wild/random relationships with no structure. On the very opposite side, a low $d_V$ (constant) means that the gates to which any input variable is connected are near one another, and hence that variables are packed in local clusters, thus exhibiting structure (typical of real-life instances). Less informally, imagine to draw a vertical line which splits the circuit in two parts (not necessarily of the same size), and count how many times such vertical line intersects a wire from any variable to any of its gates: the quantity $d_V$ is the highest number of such intersections for any such vertical line (obviously, the assumption here is that the circuit propagation flow is from bottom to top, not from left to right).

> 1. Has $d_V$ been studied in the literature of planar circuits (maybe it already has a widely used name and formal definition which I'm not aware of)? More generally, has the clustering of variables been addressed at all in the theoretical study of the computational complexity of the problem?
> 2. Does $d_V$ being sublinear (if not even constant) somehow destroys the expressive power of the planar circuit? Or does it remain $\mathbf{NP}$-complete / $\oplus \mathbf{P}$-complete?

**Side 3 - Consequences**

> 1. Would a subexponential time algorithm for $\oplus \text{PLANAR-CIRCUIT-SAT}$, assuming sublinear $d_C$ only, bring any interesting consequence?
> 2. Would a subexponential time algorithm for $\oplus \text{PLANAR-CIRCUIT-SAT}$, assuming both sublinear $d_C$ and sublinear $d_V$, bring any interesting consequence?